# Find 4 sequence numbers in String Using C#

Tags: c#, string

I have a large string, I want to find 4 sequence Numbers in string. How do I get it?

For example:

```
string a=@"I(1946) am a string and I have some character and number and some sign like 4412 but I must find 4 sequence numbers in this."
```

result expected: '1946' and '4412'

```
string a=@"2015/10/13 is my birthday.I love this date1234!"
```

result expected: '2015' and '1234'

```
string a=@"xx888xx88x9xx99x9999xx"
```

result expected: '9999'

Comment: `12345` - what is the output?

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov mm... I forgot to think over this condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do this with [regular expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), for example:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"\d{4}");            
string a=@"I(1946) am a string and I have some character and number and some sign like 4412 but I must find 4 sequence numbers in this.";
foreach(Match match in regex.Matches(a))
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
```

Live example: http://rextester.com/OXG80935

Comment: Thank for your help, this code work great ! I think I must read Regular Expression more. :x

Answer (score 1):

```
void Main()
{
    string a1 =@" I(1946) am a string and I have some character and number and some sign like 4412 but I must find 4 sequence numbers in this.";
    string a2 = @" 2015/10/13 is my birthday.I love this date1234!";    
    var reg = @"\d{4}";

    Print(Regex.Matches(a1, reg));
    Print(Regex.Matches(a2, reg));

}

private void Print(MatchCollection matches)
{
    foreach (Match element in matches)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(element.Value);
    }
}
```

output:

```
1946
4412
2015
1234
```